# Eloquent query with a RAW order by

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a eloquent query to get list items.
This is based on the idea that the sort column would be filled in, but in some circumstances it is not.
If its the case then I would like to order by the name of the list.
More or less what I wrote bellow.

`order by CASE WHEN trickysort IS NOT NULL THEN trickysort::text ELSE list_name END`

Here is the original query.

```
    $list = Table_Lists::with(["listItems" =>
                function($query)
                {
                    $query
                    ->orderBy('trickysort', 'asc')
                    ->with("sublist.listItems");
                }
            ])
            ->where("list_name","=", $name)
            ->where("hos_id","=", $hos_id)->get()->first();
    return $list ? $list->toArray() : null;
```

The table structure is as follows.

Parent table -> `table_lists`
related child table -> `table_list_items`

the child table items are the one I need sorting. ( `trickysort` else `list_name` )

I hope this makes sense.

Im was thinking kind of a RAW query bit in the `->orderBy` section of the child table.

Comment: **->orderBy(\DB::raw(CASE WHEN trickysort IS NOT NULL THEN trickysort::text ELSE list_name END)) ** Hopefully this will work out

Comment: instead of `->get()->first();` use `->first();`